# Convert jQuery view handler to Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, wai-aria

Trying to convert a lot of jQuery and JS to an Angular controller so that it works the "NG" way. I've looked at the docs and it looks like I can setup a document ready function in Angular using something like angular.element(document).ready to initialize the jQuery variable. What I am confused on is "this" and it's place in the angular world. Anyone have an idea of where to start?

Here is a Pen of what I am trying to accomplish:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbLPZQ)

And I know that there is ng-show/ng-hide and that ngAria shows up around 1.3 but I am just trying to grasp the basis for converting a lot of jQuery to angular.

Here is my current script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hs1 = new hideShow('open1', 'close1');
  var hs2 = new hideShow('open2', 'close2');
  var hs3 = new hideShow('open3', 'close3');
  var hs4 = new hideShow('open4', 'close4');
});


function hideShow(toggleID, closeID) {
  this.$toggle = $('#' + toggleID);
  this.$close = $('#' + closeID);
  this.$region = $('#' + this.$toggle.attr('aria-controls'));
  this.keys = {
    enter: 13,
    space: 32
  };

  this.toggleSpeed = 100;
  this.bindHandlers();
} 


hideShow.prototype.bindHandlers = function() {
  var thisObj = this;
  this.$toggle.click(function(e) {
    thisObj.toggleRegion();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  });
  this.$close.click(function(e) {
    thisObj.hideRegion();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  });
}


hideShow.prototype.hideRegion = function() {
  this.$region.hide().attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
  this.$toggle.find('span').html('Show');
  this.$toggle.focus();
}


hideShow.prototype.toggleRegion = function() {
  var thisObj = this;
  this.$region.slideToggle(this.toggleSpeed, function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'false') { // region is collapsed
      $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
      $(this).focus();
      thisObj.$toggle.find('span').html('Hide');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
      thisObj.$toggle.find('span').html('Show');
    }
  });
}
```

Any suggestions or examples are appreciated.

Comment: Typically, you convert DOM manipulation code (with jQuery or otherwise) into a directive, not into the controller. Then you would not need `$(document).ready` - Angular would instantiate the directive on its own

Comment: Right on. The current app is basically a bunch of jQuery functions that make it happen so trying to convert the entire thing to Angular is a bit daunting. But I see the basics where you can add a click handler within the directive like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPvwgg but if you want to change the attr state like the example above, where would that go?